# "Input string was not in a correct format" when trying to make a "menu" in windows console app

Tags: c#, string, input, formatting

I wrote this code for class a few days ago. Everything looks correct, however, when I enter the input, I immediately get an error.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Console.WriteLine("The following are the benefit packages: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Employee only (E) ");
        Console.WriteLine("Employee and spouse (S) ");
        Console.WriteLine("Employee and children (C) ");
        Console.WriteLine("Employee and family (F) ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please select your benefit type for medical insurance: ");
        string medical = Console.ReadLine();
        double subtotal = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        ///the error is with the double above. I'm not sure how to work around this.
        if (medical == "e")
        {
            subtotal += 0;
        }else if (medical == "s")
        {
            subtotal += 50;
        }else if (medical == "c")
        {
            subtotal += 100;
        }else if (medical == "f")
        {
            subtotal += 200;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please select your benefit type for dental insurance: ");
        string dental = Console.ReadLine();
        if (dental == "e")
        {
            subtotal += 50;
        }else if (dental == "s")
        {
            subtotal += 125;
        }else if (dental == "c")
        {
            subtotal += 225;
        }else if (dental == "f")
        {
            subtotal += 325;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please select your benefit type for vision insurance: ");
        string vision = Console.ReadLine();
        if (vision == "e")
        {
            subtotal += 25;
        }else if (vision == "s")
        {
            subtotal += 60;
        }else if (vision == "c")
        {
            subtotal += 110;
        }else if (vision == "f")
        {
            subtotal += 185;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your years in service: ");
        int years = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        double discount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (years >= 20)
        {
            discount = .2;
        }else if (years >= 10 && years < 20)
        {
            discount = .1;
        }else if (years < 10)
        {
            discount = 0;
        }
        double total = subtotal + (subtotal * discount);
        Console.WriteLine("Your total out-of-pocket premium: " + total);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Each time the user "selects" a package, the value of the "subtotal" will increase. Later, the final total is calculated for, giving the user a final cost of these premiums.

Comment: why do you have this line? - double subtotal = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());...it looks like its trying to read a subtotal number but your writeline statements don't indicate that the user should be even typing a number

Comment: I thought of it as: the user inputs the string (letter e, s, c, or f) and the value of the subtotal will increase.

Answer (score 0):

```
string medical = Console.ReadLine();
double subtotal = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

this is asking for two inputs, the first `Console.ReadLine();` sets your string medical. this is good.

lets say i enter `E`

now medical = "E"

now before it gets to your loop to determine what to do with "E", your asking for another input, and trying to convert it to a double. i would change the second line:

```
 double subtotal = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

to

```
 double subtotal = 0.0;
```

this will give you an starting value. if you know the "procedure cost" which i assume is your double, you can set it to whatever you want, but if you want to ask for the value use:

```
double subtotal = double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
```

also the way your options are set up....

```
 Console.WriteLine("Employee only (E) ");
        Console.WriteLine("Employee and spouse (S) ");
        Console.WriteLine("Employee and children (C) ");
        Console.WriteLine("Employee and family (F) ");
```

is going to encourage people to enter capital letters. this is fine, but you're only checking for lower case, i suggest:

```
 if (vision == "e"||vision == "E")
```

*EDIT:* i forgot to tell you, when working with dollar amounts, its best to use `decimal` not `double`.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for the help. I figured it was a fairly simple fix, I just wasn't sure how to think through it. I appreciate the tips as well and will be implementing them into my code!

Comment: yeah if this does the trick for you please accept it as the answer